# How to increase width of modal window in mobirise?

Tags: html, video, mobirise

I am using mobirise to develop interface for an Html website. In the gallery of mobirise, the videos are played by youtube by default. I have put mp4 videos instead to be played in a lightbox modal window of the gallery like this:

```
<div class="carousel-item">
  <video src="videos\ocean.mp4" autoplay loop/>
</div>
```

The videos play fine but the width of the video doesn't increase. I have tried many options but none of them works. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: <div class="carousel-item">
                           <video src="videos\ocean.mp4"   autoplay loop/>
                        </div>

Comment: Post your code? [Minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you use not a block with video background.  If you use background video you, it's stretched all over the whole display. In this case, you can't use a music. After that, you can try to use small videos in the central part of a screenshot. It can't be stretched but you can listen to any music you want.

Please remember that you can bring any changes you want to your project manually after publication.